# qProcess writing after closing write channel

Tags: c++, qt, stdin, channel, qprocess

I'm starting a new `QProcess` and writing some data into it and closing it to get the effect. It works OK, but then I need to write some more data. This doesn't works, because `WriteChannel` is already closed.

```
QProcess *_helpProcess = new QProcess();
QStringList arguments;
_helpProcess->start("../bin/help_app", arguments);
_helpProcess->write(page.toStdString().c_str());
_helpProcess->closeWriteChannel();
```

How to fix the problem? Can I reopen the channel in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Once you close the channel you close the pipe between processes. There is no way back !